# Many-to-many: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a migration using the code-first workflow, but it seems that the EF core does not recognize my many-to-many relationship between "TeamMember" and "Step" classes.

My "step" class:

```
public class Step {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "The step name must have between 3 and 30 characters!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "The step description must have between 10 and 500 characters!")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers{ get; set; }        

    public Step() {
    }
}
```

My "TeamMember" class:

```
public class TeamMember {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public User User{ get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Step> Steps{ get; set; }

    public TeamMember() {            
    }
}
```

My Context class:

```
public class ProjectContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {
    public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options)
       : base(options) {
    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Step> Steps { get; set; }        
    public DbSet<TeamMember> TeamMembers{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.Entity<User>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        builder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        builder.Entity<Team>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        builder.Entity<Step>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        builder.Entity<TeamMember>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

> Error string: Unable to determine the relationship represented by
> navigation property 'Step.TeamMembers' of type
> 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship,
> or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

As you can see I have an `ICollection` in each one of the classes and I can't figure out the error.

Comment: What is the error? How do you know the navigation property is not recognized?

Comment: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Step.TeamMembers' of type 'ICollection<TeamMember>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Edit the question with that detail, it will add clarity.

Comment: Did it, i hope the understandment is easier now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core doesn't support many to many relationships by default.

You have to create a join table in order to achieve the relationship:

You can easily configure it like this:

Step:

```cs
public class Step {
    public ICollection<TeamMemberStep> TeamMemberStep { get; set; }        
}
```

Team Member:

```cs
public class TeamMember {
    public ICollection<TeamMemberStep> TeamMemberStep { get; set; }
}
```

Join table:

```cs
public class TeamMemberStep
{
    public string TeamMemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
    public int StepId { get; set; }
    public virtual Step Step { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TeamMemberStep>()
    .HasKey(aup => new { aup.TeamMemberId, aup.StepId });

public DbSet<TeamMemberStep> TeamMemberSteps { get; set; }
```

Now you query the `TeamMemberStep` table to get your data from either sides.